# Circular dependency when trying to reopen an engine class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class-eval

I am trying to re-open a class in Rails that comes from an engine. I did the following:

```
module Xaaron
  ApiKey.class_eval do
     include Promiscuous::Publisher
     publish :xaaron_users_id, :api_key, :as => :ApiKey
  end
end
```

which sits in:

```
  models/
    Xaaron/
      api_key.rb
```

This is all in my app, which should then let me run:

```
bundle exec promiscuous publish "Xaaron::ApiKey.all"
```

But, when I do, I get the error:

```
RuntimeError: Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant Xaaron::ApiKey
```

Comment: What if you just remove the 'include' line?

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**: Try renaming `api_key.rb` to something else.

Here is what *I think* is happening: Rails autoloader loads `Xaaron/api_key.rb` and encounters an unknown constant `Xaaron::ApiKey`. It then tries to load it from file called (based on constant name)... `Xaaron/api_key.rb`. Boom, circular dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Like @artemave stated, **rename the file**. And if that does not work, try:

```
Xaaron::ApiKey.class_eval do
```